# Angularjs Get Method

Tags: php, angularjs

Getting the error below in console and data is not fetching from mysql. Can anyone suggest on the error below:

Used angularjs, php, mysql and materializecss

> Error: $http.get(...).success is not a function

Here is the code of my controller:

```
.controller('dashBoardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) 
{ 
    $http.get("dbconnection/db_read.php") 
        .success(function(data)
        { 
            $scope.data = data; 
            console.log(data); 
        }) 
        .error(function() 
        { 
            $scope.data = "error in fetching data"; 
        }); 
    }]
);
```

Comment: .controller('dashBoardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("dbconnection/db_read.php")
                
                
                .success(function(data){
                    $scope.data = data;
            console.log(data);
            
                })
                .error(function() {
                    $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
                });
        }])
    ;

Comment: If you are needing to add to your question just use the edit button instead of a comment. Then just say you have added an edit, maybe make  **EDIT** bold. And add some context around what you are adding.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
$http.get().then(function(result){console.log(result)});
```

I believe `.success` is deprecated.

Comment: It's deprecated in 1.5. It's completely removed in 1.6

Answer (score 0):

You're more than likely using AngularJS 1.6+

`.success(fnSuccess)` and `.error(fnError)` don't exist any more.

Use `.then(fnSuccess, fnError)` instead.

So

```
$http.get(...).success(function(){})
```

is now

```
$http.get(...).then(function success() {}, function error() {});
```

Comment: Thanks to all for giving your suggestions .. Issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> ```
> // Simple GET request example:
> $http({
>   method: 'GET',
>   url: '/someUrl'
> }).then(function successCallback(response) {
>     // this callback will be called asynchronously
>     // when the response is available
>   }, function errorCallback(response) {
>     // called asynchronously if an error occurs
>     // or server returns response with an error status.
>   });
> ```

So you pass your success and error callbacks to `then()` not `success()`.